# xulrunner calling external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xul, xulrunner

I am trying to make an offline app using XULRunner. I am trying to integrate [JSTree](http://www.jstree.com/) for a tree view. It doesn't appear to call the external js. The code works correctly in a normal html file. Any ideas why it doesn't in XULRunner? The code of my xul file is thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window
  id="findfile-window"
  title="Find Files"
  width="800"
  height="500"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<!--General Use jQuery
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"/>-->

<!--jstree plugin-->
<script src="jstree/_lib/jquery.js"/>
<script src="jstree/jquery.jstree.js"/>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#bibletree").jstree({
                "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data" ],
                "themes" : {
                    "icons" : false,
                    "dots" : false
                }
            });
        });
 </script>


        <html:div id="bibletree">
        <html:ul id="lvl">
            <html:li><html:a href="#">Genesis</html:a>
                <html:ul>
                    <html:li><html:a href="#">01</html:a></html:li>
                    <html:li><html:a href="#">02</html:a></html:li>
                    <html:li><html:a href="#">03</html:a></html:li>
                    <html:li><html:a href="#">04</html:a></html:li>
                    <html:li><html:a href="#">05</html:a></html:li>
                    <html:li><html:a href="#">06</html:a></html:li>
                                    ...
</window>
```

Comment: It probably doesn't work because XUL uses [flexible box layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/). Or maybe it is calling `document.createElement()` instead of `document.createElementNS()`. Either way, it probably makes more sense to use XUL trees instead of trying to make a script work that isn't meant for XUL. Of you could load that script into an XHTML document.

Comment: So am I wrong to think that the whole idea of xulrunner is to use javascript, html, and css to make on/offline apps?

Comment: It is more nuanced than that, you do use js,html and css. It's just that things are different sometimes with xulrunner.

Comment: Also have you tried just including a custom JavaScript file that just does alert("Hi, I am loaded"), this way you can know empirically that the file is or is not loaded.

Comment: @tomdemuyt I tried to put a script like this direction into the xul file: `<script>$(document).ready({alert("ready!")});</script>`. It is not called. Not sure why. According to this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/script), it should work.

Comment: ok, big DUH. I didn't realize that the syntax `$(document).ready()`
 was based on the jQuery script which I am trying to find out if it is loaded. `window.onload` works.

Comment: Another edit: with `window.onload` I made sure that some other external js was indeed loaded. It was and it called the method in that external script. So, the problem must be with jQuery. Any other ideas?

Comment: @preahkumpii: You can create offline apps with XULRunner - but if you want to use HTML then you should add a frame and load an HTML document into it. Mixing XUL with HTML has its quirks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

the document object does not have the onload or ready event in XUl, you will have to listen for 'load' in the 'window' object or use 'onload'.

Link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Events#Window_events